# Does poetry (or pip) 'install' create/have the option to deploy an executable?

Tags: pip, pyenv, python-poetry

I am running

```
poetry install
```

from within a python local *virtualenv*  "*.venv*" .  The project is supposed to create an executable `hercl` that becomes available on the user's path.   Two questions:

What options / configuration of I'm not sure if that's supposed to gets installed into the local *.venv/bin* or in the `pyenv` shims.

Since *poetry* reuses / redirects many functions to *pip* it may be the case that the feature I'm asking about is actually from *pip* itself. I have not been able to discover from either *poetry* or *pip* documentation about this shell script installation. How is this achieved?

**Update**

After running  running `pip install` *outside* of the virtualenv it pulls from `pypi` and creates a  bash script  `~/.pyenv/shims/my_app`   .

In my case the `my_app` is "hercl" and we see this:

```
$which hercl
~/.pyenv/shims/hercl
```

Its contents are :

```
$cat $(which hercl)
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
[ -n "$PYENV_DEBUG" ] && set -x

program="${0##*/}"

export PYENV_ROOT="~/.pyenv"
exec "~/.pyenv/libexec/pyenv" exec "$program" "$@"
```

Somehow this script is installed when running `pip install`: I am wondering how `pip` knows to do this.  Is it from the `pyproject.ml` from *poetry* ?  Is it from a `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` associated with `pip` ?

**Anoterh Update** @sinoroc has another tack on this:  *poetry* has a scripts section that I did not notice (noobie on that tool).

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
hercl = "hercl.hercl:main"
```

`hercl` is a command that I was looking for .

But there was *also* an actual _bash script that would launch *hercl* that got installed under the *shims* as part of the virtualenv.   i think that script were in the

Comment: Not sure what the question is. -- If a virtual environment is active then the executable is installed in the virtual environment's `bin` directory. So it is available only while the virtual environment is "active". Is that what you are wondering? -- Or are you looking for this piece of documentation: [_Poetry_'s _`scripts`_](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts)?

Comment: @sinoroc You're very much on the right track. Can you make that an answer then i can upvote and then add some additional comments?

Comment: I do not know anything about _pyenv_ shims.

Answer (score 1):

In a *Poetry*-based project such executable scripts are defined in the [*`scripts`* section](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts) of `pyproject.toml`.

If a virtual environment is active when installing the application then the executable is installed in the virtual environment's bin directory. So it is available only while the virtual environment is "active".

Comment: This is helpful info.  There are a couple of other considerations here.  1) I updated the question mentioning that an executable is placed inside the `~/.pyenv/shims` dir. 2) there is *no* executable being placed inside the *local* `~/.venv` dir